# Duplicate rows in text file depending on column value

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to duplicate a series of rows depending on an integer present in one of the columns.

For example, when considering the 4th column:

```
AATTGGCC  5.2  4.8  1
CCGGTTAA  1.8  3.3  3
ATATGCGC  1.8  4.6  1
```

My code should return:

```
AATTGGCC
CCGGTTAA
CCGGTTAA
CCGGTTAA
ATATGCGC
```

Currently, I have this code:

```
while read line; do
   for i in awk '{4}'; do
   awk '{print $1}' >> output.txt
   done
done < input.txt
```

However, all it returns is the first column from the original table.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your data in a file named `f`, you can do it simply with `awk` alone, e.g.

```
$ awk '{ n=$4; while (n--) print $1}' f
AATTGGCC
CCGGTTAA
CCGGTTAA
CCGGTTAA
ATATGCGC
```

Where you simply get the number in the 4th column and loop that many times outputting the first column on a line of its own. Let me know if you have further questions.

If you did want to do it with shell (don't, but hypothetically), you could do essentially the same thing:

```
$ while read dna n n n; do while ((n-- != 0)); do  echo "$dna"; done; done < f
AATTGGCC
CCGGTTAA
CCGGTTAA
CCGGTTAA
ATATGCGC
```

`awk` will always be orders of magnitude faster than processing with a shell loop.